# How To Get Rid Of Bloated Stomach?

Tags: nutrition, diet, digestion

I am a 27 year old male(75 kg 1.78 tall) and I do weight training for 7 years already. I do always have problem about eating. The main problem is bloating and sometimes I even feel that I have an empty stomach. I take digestive enzyme supplements every after meals but still the same. I even tried prebiotics. I started to think if I should change my diet... I consume 300 g of good source carbs, 230 g of animal source protein, and 70 g of high quality fats(olive oil, flaxseed oil, walnut oil). Totally, I consume like 2700-3000 kcal.
Thanks for any advice about my bloating problem...

Comment: Hello, if this can be re-phrased as a general question about health, please [edit] and then flag it so we can see about re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest seeing a doctor. They'd be able to get to the crux of the matter, and it could be indicative of something more serious. Especially considering bloating can be caused by so many things and you've tried most of the basics

Did you google it? There's tons of articles on bloating along with suggestions and remedies. Based on your question it seems like you have, so I'm assuming you've tried [avoiding sugar substitues](http://stomachbloating.net/sugar-substitutes-and-stomach-problems/) (splenda, aspartame, etc), carbonated drinks, and sugars, [taking enteric coated peppermint oil](http://altmedicine.about.com/od/Herbal-Remedies/fl/EntericCoated-Peppermint-Oil.htm), etc.

And again, I'd suggest seeing a doctor. Expecially since you seem to have tried all the more simple remedies.

Medical disclaimer:

> This answer is for general informational purposes only and is not a substitute for professional medical advice. If you think you may have a medical emergency, call your doctor or (in the United States) 911 immediately. Always seek the advice of your doctor before starting or changing treatment.